# win32api.ShellExecute only printing Excel files sometimes while running in a script using task scheduler

Tags: python, excel, windows, winapi, printing

I have a python program scheduled in task scheduler which calls another python program after a specific condition and print newly created Excel file which is also created by the same python code in previous lines.

After generating the Excel file on a daily basis this program should print the Excel file. Although it does the job in some day but not everyday. Any help with that?
My printing code is given below.

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", str(str(templateOut)+str(invoicedate)+'.xlsx'), 
                      None, ".", 0)
```

Here `templateout` and `invoicedate` define the name of the Excel file.

Comment: Why do you think it is ShellExecute that fails? Is the printer not on?

Comment: The printer is surely on as it prints some pdf files on previous lines and it never fails. I think it has something to do with 'xlsx' file only.